# Help with garbage disposal install and high drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

The drain pipe for my sink sits pretty high, and then the sink-bowels holes are pretty close to each other.  Below is the best my friend and I could do to make this work, and I just realized we need to baffle T to keep the pressure of the disposal from spurting out to the other bowl.  Question is, have you ever seen this High of a p-trap and it will actually work?  With water, works fine but I am afraid of using the disposal because of the low-p trap and high drain pipe for the waster to travel that high to make its way out.  I live in a condo, so cannot change anything behind the wall.  Any ideas or recommendations of how I can best make this work properly?  Much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The drain into the wall needs to be below that of the disposal and sink, there's no way to beat gravity with this. Your options are to:

1. Raise the disposal output (with a different disposal)
2. Raise the sink (with a different, shallower sink, or at least a shallow drain for the disposal)
3. Lower the drain at the wall

Answer (score 4):

As you've noticed, your disposal will always be full of water because the outlet is lower than the trap weir.

[image: Trap Weir]

A trap is measured from the top of the trap bend, to the trap weir.  This depth should be between 2 - 4" (according to plumbing codes), to maintain a proper trap.

[image: Code Trap Depth]

You'll notice that your trap depth is much more than that, and includes your garbage disposal.

[image]

The "proper" way to correct the problem in your situation, is to lower the drain pipe or get rid of the disposal.

---

### Alternative Solution:

Depending on your location, plumbing codes *may* allow gray water pumps.  If they do, you could install one so that the outlet of the sink and disposal go into the gray water basin. Then the pump outlet would connect to the drain, and pump the waste water out of the basin.

[image]

<sub>*I'm not sure if gray water pumps can be used with garbage disposals, you'd have to check with the manufacturer to be sure.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'd cap the drain at the wall then cut a hole in the floor and run a new pipe and reconnect to the drain under the floor. This is fairly easy and neat.

Comment: There's a good chance the drain isn't accessible from the floor. Most are in the wall.