# Garbage Disposal lower than wall pipe - new deeper sink

Tags: kitchen-sink, garbage-disposal

Kitchen remodel with a snafu.  Bought a deeper sink now the disposal pipe will be about an inch below the wall pipe.  Are there any disposals with the connection less than 6-1/2" from sink?  That would solve my problem.  Thanks

Comment: That's pretty standard. You'll just have to check around your home stores and plumbing supply stores.  This borders close to a shopping question and we don't like those.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/36050 which gives answers, but not shopping answers. Hint - you either get a different sink that fits your parts, don't have a disposal at all, or change the drain entry in the wall (what the heck, you're remodeling...)